# Excel Inputbox displaying 0 instead of empty string

Tags: excel, vba

I am working on an excel vba project and have run into an odd issue. I am working inside of a button click sub and want to display the current note as the default while they update the note. Unfortunately, all empty cells show up with a default value of "0". The msgbox just before is for debugging purposes and it shows "" (nothing). Any ideas?

```
MsgBox Sheet4.Range("E" & stallToAdd + 1)
inputFromUser = Application.InputBox("Update note: ", "Update Note", Sheet4.Range("E" & stallToAdd + 1))
```

Edit: inputFromUser is a variant, stallToAdd is an integer.

Comment: Try wrapping Cstr() around the value you're displaying

Comment: @TimWilliams It was trivial but you should have posted that as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just convert it to a string like this:

```
inputFromUser = Application.InputBox("Update note: ", "Update Note", _
    CStr(Sheet4.Range("E" & stallToAdd + 1)))
```